# How can I do to change the value of a value transmit in a component using react?

Tags: reactjs

I have this component :

```
<MyComponent param="true" />
```

and in the file of my component I would like to do something like that :

```
props.param = false
```

But I got `Error creating a post TypeError: "param" is read-only`

Actually, I would like to pass a value for param and then be able to modify this variable but if I call the component again I would like the value is the value in the tag.

I tried that also :

```
const [param, setParam] = useState(false);
```

But if I use that then :

```
<MyComponent param={param} />
```

I cannoot specify a value instead there `useState(false)` whereas I would like something like

```
<MyComponent param={param=false} />
```

Do you know how can I do to this ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Create a state and define a function to update state.

```
state = {
  param: true
}
```

Function to update state:

```
updateParamHandler = () => {
  this.setState({param: false});
}
```

In Component either param from state or updateParamHandler() can be passed depending on the usecase

Comment: Yes but how can you do to apply the function when you  pass it in the component ?